# Why is Action<Action<T>> covariant?

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

This is something I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around. I understand that `Action<T>` is contravariant and is probably declared as such.

```
internal delegate void Action<in T>(T t);
```

However, I don't understand **why** an `Action<Action<T>>` is covariant. `T` is still not in an **output** position. I'd really appreciate it if someone could try to explain the reasoning / logic behind this.

I dug around a little bit and found [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2009/08/31/understanding-csharp-covariance-and-contravariance-5-higher-order-functions.aspx) blog post which tries to explain it. In particular, I didn't quite follow what was meant here under the "Explanation for covariance of input" subsection.

> It is the same natural if the “Derived -> Base” pair is replaced by “Action -> Action” pair.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OK, so first of all let's be clear what you mean by saying that `Action<Action<T>>` is *covariant*. You mean that the following statement holds:

- If an object of reference type X may be assigned to a variable of reference type Y, then an object of type `Action<Action<X>>` may be assigned to a variable of reference type `Action<Action<Y>>`.

Well, let's see if that works. Suppose we have classes `Fish` and `Animal` with the obvious inheritance.

```
static void DoSomething(Fish fish)
{
    fish.Swim();
}

static void Meta(Action<Fish> action)
{
    action(new Fish());
}

...

Action<Action<Fish>> aaf = Meta;
Action<Fish> af = DoSomething;
aaf(af);
```

What does that do?  We pass a delegate to DoSomething to Meta. That creates a new fish, and then DoSomething makes the fish swim. No problem.

So far so good.  Now the question is, why should this be legal?

```
Action<Action<Animal>> aaa = aaf;
```

Well, let's see what happens if we allow it:

```
aaa(af);
```

What happens?  Same thing as before, obviously.

Can we make something go wrong here?  What if we pass something other than `af` to `aaa`, remembering that doing so will pass it along to `Meta`.

Well, what can we pass to `aaa`?  Any `Action<Animal>`:

```
aaa( (Animal animal) => { animal.Feed(); } );
```

And what happens?  We pass the delegate to `Meta`, which invokes the delegate with a new fish, and we feed the fish.  No problem.

> T is still not in an output position. I'd really appreciate it if someone could try to explain the reasoning / logic behind this.

The "input/output" position thing is a mnemonic; covariant type *tend* to have the T in the output position and contravariant type *tend* to have the T in the input position, but that is not universally true.  For the majority of cases, that's true, which is why we chose `in` and `out` as the keywords. But what really matters is that the types can only be used in a typesafe manner.

Here's another way to think about it. Covariance *preserves the direction of an arrow*.  You draw an arrow `string --> object`, you can draw the "same" arrow `IEnumerable<string> --> IEnumerable<object>`.   Contravariance *reverses the direction of an arrow*. Here the arrow is `X --> Y` means that a reference to X may be stored in a variable of type Y:

```
Fish                         -->     Animal  
Action<Fish>                 <--     Action<Animal> 
Action<Action<Fish>>         -->     Action<Action<Animal>>
Action<Action<Action<Fish>>> <--     Action<Action<Action<Animal>>>
...
```

See how that works? Wrapping `Action` around both sides *reverses* the direction of the arrow; that's what "contravariant" means: as the types vary, the arrows go in the *contra* -- opposing -- direction. Obviously reversing the direction of an arrow *twice* is the same thing as *preserving the direction of an arrow*.

FURTHER READING:

My blog articles that I wrote while designing the feature. Start from the bottom:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx

A recent question about how variance is determined to be typesafe by the compiler:

[Variance rules in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246281/variance-rules-in-c-sharp/16249179#16249179)

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thanks for clarifying that the input / output position stuff is not a definitive way to judge a type's variance. I think I was a little confused about that. I also really like the arrow analogy.

Comment: @Tejas: It's not an analogy; that's actually how covariance is *defined* in category theory. Category theory has two basic kinds of things "objects" and "arrows" that connect pairs of objects. A covariant function is one that preserves the direction of the arrow between a related pair of objects.

Comment: hmm I had no idea. Well, I'm going to go read your blog series, hopefully that should clear up an remaining doubts / misconceptions I have about variance. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example:

```
string s = "Hello World!";
object o = s; // fine
```

If we wrap it around with `Action`

```
Action<string> s;
Action<object> o;
s = o; // reverse of T's polymorphism
```

This is because `in` parameter's effect is *making the generic type's assignable hierarchy the reverse of the type parameter's hierarchy*. For example, if this is valid:

```
TDerived t1; 
TBase t2; 
t2 = t1; // denote directly assignable without operator overloading
```

then

```
Action<TDerived> at1; 
Action<TBase> at2; 
at1 = at2; // contravariant
```

is valid. Then

```
Action<Action<TDerived>> aat1;
Action<Action<TBase>> aat2;
aat2 = aat1; // covariant
```

and also

```
Action<Action<Action<TDerived>>> aaat1;
Action<Action<Action<TBase>>> aaat2;
aaat1 = aaat2; // contravariant
```

and so on.

The effect and how covariant and contravariant works comparing to normal assignment are explained in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx. In short, covariant assignment works like normal OOP polymorphism, and contravariant works backward.

Comment: yeah I understand the "rule" that enclosing a type within `Action` will flip the variance. But like I said, I don't understand the logic BEHIND that rule.

Comment: @Tejas do you mean you don't know the reason why contravariant like `in` must flip the variance?

Comment: well, Eric Lippert did a pretty good job of explaining it but I was confused about why everytime you wrap a type within `Action`, it flips the variance. You did a pretty good job of explaining it from a purely "mathematical" point of view. I was looking for a more detailed explanation of WHY this happens. Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
class Base { public void dosth(); }
class Derived : Base { public void domore(); }
```

Using Action of T:

```
// this is all clear
Action<Base> a1 = x => x.dosth();
Action<Derived> b1 = a1;
```

Now:

```
Action<Action<Derived>> a = x => { x(new Derived()); };
Action<Action<Base>> b = a;
// the line above is basically this:
Action<Action<Base>> b = x => { x(new Derived()); };
```

Which would work, because you can still treat the result of the `new Derived()` as a `Base`. Both classes can `dosth()`.

Now, in this case:

```
Action<Action<Base>> a2 = x => { x(new Derived()); };
Action<Action<Derived>> b2 = x => { x(new Derived()); };
```

It would still work, when using `new Derived()`. However, that cannot be said generally and is thus illegal. Consider this:

```
Action<Action<Base>> a2 = x => { x(new Base()); };
Action<Action<Derived>> b2 = x => { x(new Base()); };
```

Error: `Action<Action<Derived>>` expects `domore()` to exist, but `Base` only delivers `dosth()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inheritance tree, with object as the root. A path on the tree would normally look something like this

`object -> Base -> Child`

An Object of a type higher on the tree can allways be assigned to a variable of a type lower on the tree. Covariance in generic types means the realized types are related in a way that follows the tree

`object -> IEnumerable<object> -> IEnumerable<Base> -> IEnumerable<Child>`

`object -> IEnumerable<object> -> IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object> -> ...`

Contravariance means the realized types are related in a way that reverses the tree.

`object -> Action<Child> -> Action<Base> -> Action<object>`

When you go a level deeper, you have to reverse the tree again

`object -> Action<Action<object>> -> Action<Action<Base>> -> Action<Action<Child>> -> Action<object>`

p.s. with contravariance, the object hierarchy is no longer a tree, but is in fact a directed acyclic graph